# Debug a python program that shows size 1 arrays are allowed

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, debugging

For the following code,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

   

f = input("Enter value of f: ")
Ts = input("Enter value of Ts: ")
f=int(f)
Ts=int(Ts)
fs=1/Ts
fs=int(fs)
n=np.linspace(-1,1,fs)
#print(n)


#print(np.pi)
x=np.cos(2*(np.pi)*f*n*Ts)*(math.exp((-n)*Ts))

plt.scatter(n,x)
```

The error shown is `only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars`.
Can anybody tell why this error comes and how to solve and lookout and debug for such errors

Comment: What values did you enter?  What was `n`?  Which line produced the error?  Did you test subexpressions in that line?  Others have identified the `math.exp` as the problem, but you need to learn to find such problems yourself.  For simple problems like this, testing in an interactive python session is best.

Answer (score 1):

`math.exp((-n)*Ts)` attempts to call `math.exp` from the built-in `math` module on a *NumPy array* `-n * Ts`, but `math.exp` is *not* `numpy.exp`, and it has no idea about NumPy arrays and thus attempts to treat the array `-n * Ts` as a Python scalar (a *number* like 1, 2.3, etc), which fails, since arrays are *not* numbers (yet, as the error message says, "size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars", so code like `math.exp(np.array([3]))` is fine).

You could use `np.exp` instead of `math.exp`.

Answer (score 1):

Changing:

```
x=np.cos(2*(np.pi)*f*n*Ts)*(math.exp((-n)*Ts))
```

to:

```
x=np.cos(2*(np.pi)*f*n*Ts)*(np.exp((-n)*Ts))
```

**That's will fix the problem.**

**But** I think you got some problems there, I am not sure exactly what are you trying to do, but after this three lines:

```
Ts=int(Ts)
fs=1/Ts
fs=int(fs)
```

"fs" will end up with value 0 no matter what are your inputs: